# Groovy date formatting problem

Tags: groovy, date-format

I am developing a groovy application and I am having problems when showing a Date field.

If I use the following notation:

```
<g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${fieldValue(bean: incidentTicketSLAInstance, field: "erstellungsDatum")}"/>
```

I am getting the actual date instead of what is saved at the DB.

When I use this notation it works properly.

```
<g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${incidentTicketSLAInstance?.erstellungsDatum}" />
```

am I doing something wrong here? 
Are not both notations equivalent? 
(BTW, the instance DO exists and erstellungsDatum is NOT null)

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fieldValue call will return a String, not a Date object, which the makes formatDate not work correctly

You have to use the second notation (as you spotted)